# React Native Signed APK Error on Visual Studio

Tags: react-native

When I put the commend on VCode for React Native App

```
keytool -genkeypair -v -storetype PKCS12 -keystore my-upload-key.keystore 
-alias my-key-alias -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000
```

Then showing this error

```
keytool : The term 'keytool' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, 
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the 
name, or if a path was included, 
verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ keytool -genkeypair -v -storetype PKCS12 -keystore my-upload-key.keys 
...
+ ~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (keytool:String) [], 
CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

How I solved the problem and generet an APK file from React Native Project

Answer (score 0):

First you should go to your JDK directory,
Then you should run that command.

Please follow the documentation step by step and read it line by line.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android

[image]

Comment: I can't Find JDK or Java folder on my C: Drive

Comment: Check this directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdkx.x.x_x\bin